# Custom plugin causes image upload to fail

Tags: wordpress

When i edit a page, and then click on Add Media. In the Media Library tab, there is a loading image that never stops spinning. Then i click on the Upload file tab and try to upload an image, when i do i got this error message "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.".

So i started desactivating plugins to see if one of them is causins this, and indeed one custom plugin i created is causing this, and i don't know why

This plugin contains a master class, where i declared two plugins

```
/*
Plugin Name: blabla
Description: blabla
Version: 0.1
Author: User
*/

include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/liste_emplois.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/candidature.php';

class Manitou_Plugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('widgets_init', function(){register_widget('Manitou_Liste_Widget');});
        add_action('widgets_init', function(){register_widget('Manitou_Candidature_Widget');});
    }
}
```

And my two plugins contain almost the same thing and same structure, here is one of them

```
class Manitou_Liste_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
                'Manitou_Liste',
                __('blabla', 'wpb_widget_domain'),
                array('description' => __('blabla'),)
        );
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        wp_enqueue_script('tablesorter', '/wp-content/plugins/manitou/scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('manitou-affichages', '/wp-content/plugins/manitou/scripts/manitou-affichages-3.0.1.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('xdomainrequest', '/wp-content/plugins/manitou/scripts/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('initmanitou', '/wp-content/plugins/manitou/scripts/initmanitou.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('manitou-affichages', '/wp-content/plugins/manitou/css/manitou-affichages.css');
        echo __("<div id='manitou_affichages'></div>", 'wpb_widget_domain');
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    }

}

function wpb_load_widget3() {
    register_widget('Manitou_Liste_Widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget3');
```

Do you see anithing that can cause the upload problem ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: is there any error in the console ?

Comment: it may be the jquery conflicts

Comment: comment  wp_enqueue_script  one by one and check  if there any conflict.

Comment: But the code in the widget function is only called in frontend isn't it ? Anyway i removed all the scripts and changed nothing, and there are no errors in the console!

Comment: comment the lines in the contruct add_action('widgets_init', function(){register_widget('Manitou_Liste_Widget');});
        add_action('widgets_init', function(){register_widget('Manitou_Candidature_Widget');});      and check.

Comment: Even if i remove everything, and only keep empty classes, i still got the error, that's really weird